# Select2 Input Box Results not changing Background Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the Select2 Input CSS/jQuery framework (https://select2.org/) to help me with my multi select boxes. I am unable to change the background of the results of the select box when clicked on.

I've provided a JS fiddle for you guys to understand a bit better.

https://jsfiddle.net/L26bzgmf/

This is the select box I'm working on:

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Tag 1</option>
    <option value="2">Tag 2</option>
    <option value="3">Tag 3</option>
    <option value="4">Tag 4</option>
</select>
```

When the box is clicked I need the four tags to appear in white text, with a background of #333333. Then when the results are selected as you can see by the auto selected Tag 1, I need that background color to change from the grayish color to #666666, and the font white, and the "remove" x to be white and when hovered it needs to turn to #aa0000.

I've tried using jQuery, I've tried using CSS... I just can't seem to get them to change. At all. Its annoying. Their documentation used to be pretty good, but now it's just... I can't figure it out. I'm also up for alternative options similar to Select2 for this purpose.

I'm creating a "tags" system for my blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer! Here is my CSS Code that allowed me to change the styling of it. I KNEW i could do this with ONLY CSS and that there was no need for any type of javascript needed.

```
/* Results "Dropdown/DropUp" */
.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

/* Clear "X" */
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    color: #cccccc;
}

/* Clear "X" Hover */
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover {
    color: #aa0000;
}
/* Each Result */
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

I also tried to update the JS Fiddle, but it didn't work... So here's a screenshot instead. :P

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCDit.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you open browser web console, you will find JQuery Select2 plugin does below things:

1. add one `<span class="select2">` placed immediately after your `.select2-multi`
2. create one `<span class="selection">` whose id="`$('span[aria-owns]', **'the span created at Step 1'**).attr('aria-owns')`"under document.body then use position=absolute to place it above your `<select>`

If you want to customize something, just look into above two Dom tree to do what you like.

Below is one demo:

```js
$('.select2-multi').select2()
let select2Obj = $('.select2-multi+.select2')
$('span', select2Obj).css('background-color', '#666666')
$('.select2-multi').on('select2:open', function () {
  setTimeout(()=>{//some elements will be created after open, so have to use setTimeout
    let select2Obj = $('.select2-multi+.select2')
    //change the background-color for select
    //you can uncomment below codes to see its structure
    //console.log($('.select2-container').html())
    //below change the background color for all options
    $('#'+$('span[aria-owns]', select2Obj).attr('aria-owns'))
      .find('li')
      .css('background-color', '#333333')
    //below change the font color for all options
    $('#'+$('span[aria-owns]', select2Obj).attr('aria-owns'))
      .find('li')
      .css('color', 'white')
    $('#'+$('span[aria-owns]', select2Obj).attr('aria-owns'))
      .find('li')
      .hover(function(){
        $(this).css('color', 'black')
      }, function() {
          $(this).css('color', 'white')
        }
      )

    //below change the font color for the selected option
    $('#'+$('span[aria-owns]', select2Obj).attr('aria-owns'))
      .find('li[aria-selected=true]')
      .css('color', 'red')
    //below change the font color for <select>
    $('>span>span>span', select2Obj).css('color', 'blue')
    //below change the background color for the arrow of <select>
    $('>span .select2-selection__arrow', select2Obj).css('background-color', 'red')
    },0)
})

//customize the tags
$('.select2-multi').on('change', function () {
  $('ul li span', select2Obj).css('color', 'white')
  $('ul li', select2Obj).css('color', 'white')
  $('ul li', select2Obj).css('background-color', 'gray')
  $('ul li', select2Obj).hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#aa0000')
  },function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray')
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Tag 1</option>
    <option value="2">Tag 2</option>
    <option value="3">Tag 3</option>
    <option value="4">Tag 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I mean that works, yea, but like thats a TON of code. I feel as though there should be a way to do this using the Select2 Docs and CSS and not having to use all this javascript.

Comment: if only need to customize some of select2, not all, this will be one option. if you’d like to apply new styles for all, uses css selector will be better like what you did.